# Authentication and Protection of API using Google and OpenID Connect

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, openid, google-openid, google-signin

I am trying to integrate the Google Sign-in mechanism with OpenID Connect into my web application. The app has a Rails frontend just for rendering the web pages and it is connected to a backend written in Erlang. I will use the Google Sign-in Button but I want to centralize the Authentication in the backend, so that I could Authenticate users and also protect the backend API either using the Rails frontend or via cURL.

Therefore, I found this library https://github.com/ianbarber/Erlang-GoogleApis-Example/ that seems to be useful for calling the Google API, and if it is possible to authenticate, fetch the user's data, store it into the database, send the response to Rails and then the frontend will render the website.

The questions I have are the following:

- In order to protect the Backend API, should I allow only POST requests that include in the headers the Access_Token or ID_Token given by Google? Or is this still not enough?
- There are two other servers who need to perform certain POST operations. Only they should able to do those requests. How can I establish different levels of authorization for them? Because users shouldn't perform those API calls.

I saw there are other approaches such as generating an API_KEY and API_SECRET_KEY but my boss don't want me to use such approach, so maybe with OpenID Connect I can carry out the authentication of users, but also the protection of the whole API.

Thanks in advance.